# Flutter: How to run a function without a button?

Tags: flutter, automation, flutter-web

In my dummy app I have a **TextField()** widget and a **Text()** widget.

This app takes input from the user, does some processing, and displays output in the Text widget.

> **What I want is: When I type something in the TextField, after 3 sec I want the function to execute.**

*(Example - If I had a Button widget, then when I press it, it execute a function. I want this kind of functionality without the user having to press the button.*

```
String text = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Enter text here...",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)))),
              onChanged: (string) {
                setState(() {
                  text = string;
                });
              },
            ),
            Text(text),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function inside oninit in statefull widget

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {

// Here you can write your code


});
```

Comment: I tried this approach,  It does delay the text but again it runs setState for all characters. I want setState to roun only once when I stop typing.

Comment: I guess there are no any functions available to detect user is typing or not, But we can wait for particular time and update that values that user typed. As you says delaying is working, if you set state after that it will update those words only

Comment: As you said "But we can wait for particular time and update that values that user typed." this is what I want. But what happens is - if we are waiting for 3 sec then each character will appear after 3 sec instead of everything appearing after 3 sec. And for each character the app is rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

this is some rough idea, you can modify code as per your need

```
Timer _timer; //place this on top of stf where it is extending
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Search",
    hintText: "Search Customer",
    // prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius:
            BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)))),
        onChanged: (string) { //what you are typing will be save in this string variable, you can use this to show in text widget
        _timer = new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 400), () {

            call_functions(); //your function to call
        });
            
    },
),
//make sure you dispose, to save memory
@override
void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _timer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: In the place of call_functions(), I have setState() and be because of this it builds app for every change in the TextField().

Comment: What I want is, once I stop typing, it should execute setState() and change the value of variable. eg- Displaying what I typed in a text widget, just delayed.

Comment: it will do same, just remove call_functions(); line and add setState() lines as per your requirement, this setState will execute each time you type something in TextField after a given delay

Comment: I've added the dummy code, In that whatever I type is displayed as it is. But the only problem is - It builds for every keystroke.  But what I'm looking for is - once I complete typing (indicated by not typing for 1-2 seconds) it rebuilds the app and text inside Text() is updated.